# Issue about Worklight Authentication NonValidatingLoginModule

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

As the title asked,

I use worklight Authentication Strategy.

I try a basic sample.

But I encounter a problem,

I'm sure that my login module is set to NonValidatingLoginModule.

According to [official document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_non_validating_login_module.html), it's mean:

*The non-validating login module accepts any user name and password passed by the authenticator.*

Unfortunately,

When I use an api register to Worklight Server,

```
var pushAppRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("SampleAppRealm");

function startLogin(){
    var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
    var options = {};
    options.parameters = {
        j_username : "Eric",
        j_password : "123"
    };
    options.headers = {};
    pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);
}
```

I always get the error message that said,

*CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID Eric. An invalid user ID or password was specified.*

Above all, did I missing something else ?

Thanks for advice.

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="MyTest">
    <testUser realm="SampleAppRealm"/>
    <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
</mobileSecurityTest> 

<realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
</realm>

<loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="3600">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>
```

Comment: Add your challenge handler implementation. Also, did you run the sample app?

Comment: Yes I just move some code from the sample app.
base on the sample code, I implement these method also
- isCustomResponse,
- handleChallenge,
- submitLoginFormCallback

Comment: Yes, sample code work perfectly.

Comment: Then please provide your sample for debugging.

Comment: Just create an new MF project. and then edit authenticationConfig.xml like mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not going to create my own project. I don't have problems, you do. So please provide your code. This is a programming website.

Comment: ok I'll package my code later, thanks for replying.